# do we need to write EOF when we try to write into a file

Tags: c++, eof, ostream

when I try to write into a file, do I need to input EOF as well, or after inputting, it is systematically there?  (C++)

Comment: Please add which language your using and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I am using C++, thanks

Comment: He meant add it to the tags. I did that for you.

Comment: EOF is detected when there's no more data to read.  When you write to a file, you don't need to write a special character; closing the file means that the file has a fixed size and EOF will be reported when reading and the read offset reaches the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

EOF is not a real character, it's just a presentation of the end of a file used by some libs or languages. So, when you read a file, you may get an EOF at the end, but when you write a file, you just write everything, flush and close the output stream. That's all.

Comment: +1 for 'EOF is not a real character'.  Be aware, though, that terminals confuse things because there's a character (often Control-D) that simulates EOF.  More precisely, it flushes any pending data to the read queue; if there is no pending data, then a read gets zero bytes returned which is what you get on EOF.  Also complicating things is Control-Z in text files on DOS systems; that is an EOF character.

Answer (score 0):

On modern operating systems, files are not terminated by EOF (end of file) characters. EOF characters you'd be working with in C++ or another programming language are just a convenience provided by the language.

You do not need write EOF. All you need to do is write to the stream (probably an ofstream,) flush and close the stream and you're done.